# Texture not appearing in render?

Tags: rendering, materials, texturing

I'm noticing a significant difference between when my objects are observable in the 3D View and when the objects are rendered.

Both objects have a material with toon settings and each have materials (incorrectly?) added to the object. the human mesh has separate textures for the head and body. The sword and the human mesh both have *mapping > coordinate* set to UV and *Mapping > Map* set to UVMap, however only the head texture seems to show up properly, and the sword texture doesn't show up at all.

[image: 3D View]

[image: Rendered view]

[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can not see it because of bad lighting. The highlights and shadows are just much more apparent than the texture color.

Move your lamps around and you will see that the texture is actually there. The body textures however are missing from the file you uploaded.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Aha, very cool, glad to see the sword is actually working. Thanks!

Erm, do you have any idea why the blend file wouldn't include the models 2nd texture?

Comment: Have you clicked 'File'->'External Data'->'Pack All Into .blend'? This should usualy pack all external textures into the .blend file. If the first texture was created inside Blender, it might have been already saved internally.

Comment: I had not! This new download link seems to have the texture correctly: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29710 . Any idea why the body texture is so warped during rendering?

Comment: @StephenSchroeder I'm not sure what you mean.. If it's not directly related, perhaps you could ask it as a new question?

Comment: In the original I posted that only the head is showing up properly in render- the body and sword weren't. Although as maddin pointed out, the sword was fine, but just not well lit. The Body texture still isnt rendered properly

Comment: @StephenSchroeder Ideally we keep posts to one question only, this helps avoid clutter and make posts easier to read for people coming in from search engines. Imo the issue with the textures is separate enough to make a separate post. Thanks :)